# System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101 won't be resolved

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller

I'm trying to solve this error, but everything that I have been trying hasn't resolved it. No problems appear when I save the file, but when I preview the visual force page, the "Too many SOQL queries" error appears. I've separated the line that it links the error to. If anyone has some insight as to why this error keeps popping up, it would be greatly appreciated, as I don't have a lot of knowledge on SOQL queries currently.

We are trying to create a drop-down on a Visualforce page that pulls through all Contact List Views in Alphabetical order. Currently, they are showing up, but they are sorted by ID, causing users to become frustrated when they cannot find their assigned lists.

```
public class ContactListViewClass {
   public List<SelectOption> listViewNames{get; set;}
   public String conFilterName{get; set;}

   public ContactListViewClass(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
ApexPages.StandardSetController mySetCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController([SELECT Id FROM Contact LIMIT 1]);

   List<Id> listViewIds = new List<ID>();

   for(SelectOption so :mySetCon.getListViewOptions()){
       listViewIds.add(so.getValue());
       }

   for(ListView lv :[SELECT Id, Name FROM ListView WHERE ID IN :listViewIds ORDER BY Name ASC]){
       List<SelectOption> listViewNames = new List<SelectOption>();
       listViewNames.add(new SelectOption(lv.Id, lv.Name));

        String q = 'SELECT Name FROM Contact LIMIT 1'; //Any object whose list view you are trying to retrieve.
```

```
    ApexPages.StandardSetController ACC = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(q));
```

```
        List<SelectOption> ListViews = ACC.getListViewOptions();
      //  List<SelectOption> listViewNames = new List<SelectOption>();
        for(SelectOption w : ListViews ){
            listViewNames.add(new SelectOption(w.getLabel(), w.getLabel()));
            }
      //listViewNames= [SELECT Name,SobjectType FROM ListView WHERE SobjectType = 'Contact' order by Name DESC];
        } 
    }
}
```

**visualforce page**

```
    <apex:selectList value="{!conFilterName}" size="1" id="filterMenu">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!listViewNames}" />
        <!-- <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!resetFilter}" rerender="contactENlistview" status="ajaxStatus"/>-->
    </apex:selectList>
```

**Updated Code as of 4:22 pm pacific**

```
      public class NitishContactListViewClass {

       public List<SelectOption> listViewNames{get; set;}
       public String conFilterName{get; set;}

       public NitishContactListViewClass(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
       List<SelectOption> listViewNames = new List<SelectOption>();

       for(ListView lv :[SELECT Id, Name FROM ListView WHERE SObjectType='Contact' ORDER BY Name ASC]){
            listViewNames.add(new SelectOption(lv.Id, lv.Name));

        }
    }
    }
```

[image: Current visual of visualforce page]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are creating a SetController (the line you separated) you're, in essence, running a SOQL query. You can't do that inside of a for-loop or you'll hit a governor limit (as you just have).

Also, you are creating and destroying the listview collection inside the loop every time.

The simplified code below will give you all the listviews for the Contact object.

```
public ContactListViewClass(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

   listViewNames = new List<SelectOption>();

   for(ListView lv :[SELECT Id, Name FROM ListView WHERE SObjectType='Contact' ORDER BY Name ASC]){
       listViewNames.add(new SelectOption(lv.Id, lv.Name));

    }
}
```

NOTE: If you add more details (in your original post) to what you're trying to do, I can try to refine this code

Comment: Hi Sebastian, I have updated the question! We are trying to organize a drop-down list of List Views for users on a Visualforce page. Currently, they show up but are sorted by List View ID, causing users to be unable to find the views they need.

Comment: Did you try the snippet I put there? Should do just that, assuming you want "Contact" listviews

Comment: Yes, I'm now receiving error: 

SELECT Id, Name FROM ListView WHERE SObjectName='Contact' ORDER BY Name
                                    ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:37
No such column 'SObjectName' on entity 'ListView'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Comment: Gosh, that was a typo. It should be `SObjectType`. I changed the snippet

Comment: Ok, great! I've tried this update, and now I'm seeing my drop-down but it hasn't retrieved any of the list views, so it's empty. (I've got roughly 300 created as a test and have double checked that they are all SObjectType Contact...) thank you so much for helping with this!  My coworker and I have been struggling with this code for the vast majority of the day and your help is really appreciated.

Comment: Hmm. If you copied the code verbatim (the entire function) this should work. Can you add the VF side? (not all the page, just the part that displays the dropdown)

Comment: Hi Sebastian, his has been added to the end of the question under the "Visualforce page" bolded text.

Comment: This should work. Plug the query in the Develoment Console and see if that one returns values. Also check that the listviews aren't private (which probably aren't, but helps to check). And, I know I said it before, check that my code are yours are verbatim identical.

Comment: I've updated the question to include what our code looks like now and have double-checked that all of the list views are public, but they are still pulling through no results. I've also posted a picture of how the Visualforce page is previewing...

Comment: Your code is not verbatim to mine, You have an extra `List<SelectOption>` that you have to remove.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I didn't realize we had overlooked that one part. We can now see our lists drop down! Unfortunately, when we try to select a list view, it shows error: "Could not find requewed ListView: '00B0e000007bIOGEA2'. Please contact your administrator." Is this maybe because it's the 18 char length ID?